# Get all files modified in last 30 days in a directory

Tags: find, centos

CentOS. Need to find files modified in last 30 days to see if any of them have been infected with malware.

I tried this:

```
root@server [/home/someuser/public_html/]# find . -mtime +30
 -exec ls -l {} > last30days.txt \;
```

But instead of the last 30 days, it seems to have found everything. 22,000 files.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

A couple of issues

- You're not limiting it to files, so when it finds a matching directory it will list every file within it.
- You can't use `>` in `-exec` without something like `bash -c '... > ...'`. Though the `>` will overwrite the file, so you want to redirect the entire `find` anyway rather than each `-exec`.
- `+30` is `older` than 30 days, `-30` would be modified in last 30 days.
- `-exec` really isn't needed, you could list everything with various `-printf` options.

Something like below should work

```
find . -type f -mtime -30 -exec ls -l {} \; > last30days.txt
```

Example with `-printf`

```
find . -type f -mtime -30 -printf "%M %u %g %TR %TD %p\n" > last30days.txt
```

This will list files in format "permissions owner group time date filename". `-printf` is generally preferable to `-exec` in cases where you don't have to do anything complicated. This is because it will run faster as a result of not having to execute subshells for each `-exec`. Depending on the version of `find`, you may also be able to use `-ls`, which has a similar format to above.

Comment: I just want to create a file that, hopefully, I could look through in vim or in Excel and see if any of the recently modified files are unusual. We normally only modify certain files. If there are additional files, that could tell us the source of the malicious code. I copied the `exec` version from somewhere on the internet. Could you add a `printf` example and explain why it is better? I suppose it has more formatting options, yes?

Comment: @ButtleButkus Added `-printf` example.

Comment: if you add a `.` just after the find, as in `find . -type f -mtime -30 -exec ls -l {} \;` it will do the search in the current directory

Comment: The best answer by far.

Answer (score 3):

Using https://github.com/sharkdp/fd:

`fd . --changed-within "30 days" /path/to/search`